# Alignment issue when running simulator

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am trying to run a simple sample using a nib file and it looks like this
[image]

However when I run it in my simulator it looks like this
[image]

My question is why is the alignment of the simulator not correct ?
The elements should be close to the middle and the screen height should be longer. Any suggestions on how I could fix this ? I am using Xcode 6.2

Here are the things I tried so far :

1 ) I made sure that the alignment in my nib file is set to Auto Layout.

These are the details of my project. I am testing on an iphone 6 as my simulator.

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can fix this ?

Comment: cause your nib is for iPad and you are runnung it on iphone

Comment: how do u know its for ipad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Constrain in AutoLayout if u don't want to use auto-layout then u can unCheck it .. you can refer this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure *size classes* for the class device that you use.

If your app is only for iphone, you can also disable size and keep size classes for iphone only.

[image]

**Hint** Use preview from: Assistant editor -> Automatic > Preview, you will be able to see a preview of the view with all device screen sizes